# CakePHP 2.x - query error - how to see details

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

How can I see details for [THIS](http://i47.tinypic.com/2a0hmbp.png):

Query is GREAT but I don't know why it won't log in so, how can I see details why ERROR AFFECTED is 1?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Error" and "Affected" are 2 different columns. In this screenshot your query does not generate any error, but 1 row is "affected": the returned row from your query.